# Why isn't this a sufficient proof?

Tags: proof-writing, automata

So basically, we have a question that asks us to prove that given a particular [Deterministic finite automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) (DFA), there is a symbol for which we can get to a state $q$ from a state $p$ given a function that takes $a$ and $q$ as arguments.

Can't we just show a particular instance for which that is true? For instance when a is equal to epsilon? What constitute a sufficient proof anyways? I thought by using contradiction for instance and showing it's not true or it is true for a particular case was sufficient.

Comment: In mathematics a proof isn't sufficient unless it covers all possible cases.

Comment: You'll probably get more helpful feedback if you provide some more details about the problem. What exactly was the question? How was it phrased? From the confusion you're having, it seems that the precise wording might be important.

Comment: Let's say you want to prove that $n^2 + n - 1$ is always prime when n is a positive integer greater than 1. Plugging $n=2$, we get a result of 5, which is prime. Therefore $n^2 + n - 1$ is always prime, right?

Comment: but we're saying there is one symbol and that symbol can be anything, so we only need one case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Can't we just show a particular instance for which that is true? For instance when a is equal to epsilon?"

1. No: a proof of a proposition, lemma, theorem, etc... must establish that all the claims make by it are true given the assumptions in the proposition, lemma, etc...

"What constitute a sufficient proof anyways? I thought by using contradiction for instance and showing it's not true or it is true for a particular case was sufficient."

1. To show  a proposition, lemma, theorem, etc... is false, it is enough to exhibit one counter-example.So it is easier (in theory) to prove that something is false than it is true because to establish it is true (to prove it), you need to cover all possible cases.
2. A common (an old) technique of proving statements is "proof by contradiction" or *reductio ad absurdum*. There you create a new statement that says that your original statement (the one you want to prove) is false. Next you provide a counter-example to it. By doing so, you prove that the statement that says your original statement is false is false, which means your original statement is true.

Comment: but we're saying there is one symbol and that symbol can be anything, so we only need one case.